# Is there a function for seeing how and how many times words from a variable appear in another variable with a dataset in R?

Tags: r, string-matching

I need help for find a code in R: I have a file excel composed from different variables, but i need to compare two variables (in my case are both name of people), for seeing if the names in the first variables(column) appear in the second variable (column) and how many times. Are very big dataset with a lot of row.
Thank you in advance!!

The Data is given as,

```
df <- structure(
    list(
        Inv_name = c(
            "Meyer, Helmut-Walter, Prof. Dr. sc.",
            "Fröhlich, Hans-Otto, Prof. Dr.",
            "Göbel, Andreas",
            "Klein, Wilfried",
            "Scholz, Peter, Dr.",
            "Hipler, Bernd",
            "Sammler, Marina",
            "Kreisel, Günter, Dr.",
            "Haupt, Kerstin",
            "Bayer, Ulrich",
            "Schmidt, Jürgen",
            "Furche, Thomas",
            "Thorwirth, Günter",
            "Kowalski, Peter",
            "Geiler, Hans-Dieter, Dr.",
            "Wagner, Matthias, Dr.",
            "RIESENBERG, Dieter",
            "SCHULZ, Volker",
            "KNORRE, Wofgang",
            "POHL, Hans, Dieter"
        ),
        Prio_Year = c(
            1990,
            1990,
            1990,
            1990,
            1990,
            1990,
            1990,
            1990,
            1990,
            1990,
            1990,
            1990,
            1990,
            1990,
            1990,
            1990,
            1990,
            1990,
            1990,
            1990
        ),
        Firma = c(
            "Gustav Peters",
            "id - Informationsdienst, Geschäftsvermittlung, Handelsvertretung, Marketing Kursawe & Klein OHG",
            "\"Heizhaus-Service\" Ingenieurbüro Wilfried Gärtner",
            "MAX LINDAU OHG Inhaber: Gerhard und Klaus-Dieter Lindau",
            "Werther Götze \"Erfordia Numismatica\"",
            "STUDIO 1 - John & Ziemann",
            "Arwico-Arenswald & Wichmann OHG",
            "Moschkowitz & Co. Schweißtechnik-Vertriebs KG",
            "Fahrschule Simon & Frauendorf",
            "Elmera Vertrieb Frank Fleischmann OHG",
            "OHG Friseur Walschleben",
            "Baumarkt Hartmut Seliger",
            "\"Thüringer MarketingService - Hoffmann & Co. OHG\"",
            "Walter Reuning Fleisch-Wurstwaren Inhaber Brigitte Pfautsch",
            "Thüringer Allgemeine Verlag GmbH & Co, KG",
            "Autoservice Grohmann-Lämmerhirt OHG",
            "\"Sippel und Thomas Video - Land\" Offene Handelsgesellschaft",
            "Paul Krause",
            "Alois Reuter - Stapler-Instandsetzung",
            "Rudolf Städtler Inhaber Willy Städtler"
        ),
        Ersteintrag = structure(
            c(
                -2209075200,
                643420800,
                643248000,
                645235200,
                646617600,
                646617600,
                646617600,
                646963200,
                648432000,
                648432000,
                649382400,
                648777600,
                648950400,
                648950400,
                649468800,
                650073600,
                650678400,
                -2156112000,
                650678400,
                650678400
            ),
            tzone = "UTC",
            class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt")
        )
    ),
    row.names = c(NA,-20L),
    class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame")
)
```

The aim is to compare the the elements in `Inv_name` sequentially against all indices in `Firma`, and count number of partial matches such that if `df$Inv_name[[1]] = "A"` then the count would be `2`, if `df$Firma = c("A GMBH", "B GMBH", "A Inc")`.

for (i in 1:nrow(df1)){

- 
- ```
  # Extract the Inv_name
  ```
- ```
  # as a matrix; this will be our pattern search
  ```
- ```
  # along the Firma
  ```
- ```
  tmpName <- str_to_lower(
  ```
- ```
      str_split(df1$Inv_name[i],pattern = ",",simplify = T)
  ```
- ```
  )
  ```
- 
- ```
  # Create a new variable that counts the number of
  ```
- ```
  # occurences of the id
  ```
- ```
      str_detect(
  ```
- ```
          string  = str_to_lower(df1$Firma),
  ```
- ```
          pattern = paste(tmpName, sep = "", collapse = "|")
  ```
- ```
  )
  ```
- 
- ```
  # NOTE: That it it cannot count correctly
  ```
- ```
  # due to titles like Dr. Mr. and MS.
  ```
- ```
  # If you are certaing about the pattern on
  ```
- ```
  # how these titles are generated then we can ignore these.
  ```
- ```
  # Here we remove all matches on the form Dr. Mr. Ms.
  ```
- ```
  tmpName <- str_remove_all(
  ```
- ```
      tmpName,
  ```
- ```
      pattern = "[:alpha:]+[:punct:][:blank:]+"
  ```
- ```
  )
  ```
- 
- ```
  # We then recount without titles
  ```
- ```
  # to avoid confusion
  ```
- ```
  df1$count2[i] <- sum(
  ```
- ```
      str_detect(
  ```
- ```
          string  = str_to_lower(df1$Firma),
  ```
- ```
          pattern = paste(tmpName, sep = "", collapse = "|")
  ```
- ```
      )
  ```
- ```
  )
  ```
- 
- }
  Warning messages:
  1: Unknown or uninitialised column: `count1`.
  2: Unknown or uninitialised column: `count2`.

> tmpName
> [1] NA

Comment: some sample data would really help

Comment: I have one column with names of invetor( extracted from reg-patent inventor.) and a column with names of commercial registrations. I have to find out if the names of inventors matching with names of commercial registrations.

Comment: Assume that you data is called `df`, then execute the following code `dput(head(df,n = 20))`, and copy-paste the result in your post so we can help you properly!

Comment: WHAT i have to compare is Inv_name AND Firma

Comment: In the post! :-) Not in the comments!

Comment: So - what is it you want to compare? Do you want to see whether the first row of `Inv_name` is contained in the first row `Firma` and so forth?

Comment: I want to see if the first row( and after also the other rows) of Inv_name is contained inside the list of Firma( not only in the first row) . But they cal also be not exactly the same. For example in Inv_name I ca have Markus Schmidt, and in Firma Markus Schmidt GmbH. And then I want to write somewhere else the names which appear in both lists.

Comment: Ive edited your post. The problem you are trying to solve is somewhat simple, but slightly cumbersome. Hopefully the edits made, will shed a clear light on the problem so you will get help. I will look into this later, if no one responded! Good luck with your project.

Comment: In the mean time I would strongly advice you to get familiar with Stackoverflow and how to post questions and do proper layouts etc.

See for example the following: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Thank you very much for you edit and for your time, hope that I can find a solution

Answer (score 0):

---

The function that you are looking for is `str_detect()` from the `stringr`-package.

---

This is what I would, probably, do. Please note that this solution assumes that you have a dataframe `df`, that has less than 500k indices. If more than this, the algorithm provided might take too much time to run. But test it, and see how it goes.

If you do not have the relevant packages installed, run the following line of code,

```
install.packages("tidyverse")
library("tidyverse")
```

Also, I generated a generic `df` to point out potential pitfalls in doing `string-matching`.

**The data**

```
df <- data.frame(
    id     = c("Dr. A,D"," Mr. B,C", "Ms. E,F,D"),
    string = c("ABC Bankrupt","ADEF LTD", "D GMBH")
)
```

Here `id` corresponds to `Inv_name` and `string` to `Firma`. **If** you are certain that Surname and Name are seperated identically across all indices, we can easily seperate the names by `str_split`.

In the generic `df` I assumed that names are constructed as Surname, Name(s). So for example the third indices is Ms. F-D E, ie. her name is F-D with Surname E and title Ms.

We can then run the following code,

```
for (i in 1:nrow(df)){
    
    # Extract the Inv_name
    # as a matrix; this will be our pattern search
    # along the Firma
    tmpName <- str_to_lower(
        str_split(df$id[i],pattern = ",",simplify = T)
    )
    
    # Create a new variable that counts the number of 
    # occurences of the id
    df$count1[i] <- sum(
        str_detect(
            string  = str_to_lower(df$string),
            pattern = paste(tmpName, sep = "", collapse = "|")
        )
    )
    
    # NOTE: That it it cannot count correctly
    # due to titles like Dr. Mr. and MS.
    # If you are certaing about the pattern on
    # how these titles are generated then we can ignore these.
    # Here we remove all matches on the form Dr. Mr. Ms.
    tmpName <- str_remove_all(
        tmpName,
        pattern = "[:alpha:]+[:punct:][:blank:]+"
    )
    
    # We then recount without titles
    # to avoid confusion
    df$count2[i] <- sum(
        str_detect(
            string  = str_to_lower(df$string),
            pattern = paste(tmpName, sep = "", collapse = "|")
        )
    )
    
}
```

Which yields the following,

```
         id       string count1 count2
1   Dr. A,D ABC Bankrupt      2      3
2   Mr. B,C     ADEF LTD      1      1
3 Ms. E,F,D       D GMBH      2      2
```

Notice that in `count1` there is a mistake, the algorithm missed all A's in the `string` as initially the algorithm compares `Dr. A` and `D` seperately. This produces unexpected results (As I assume that `Dr.` is a generic title, that you do not want to count). Therefore we need to remove `Dr.` from `Dr. A`.

**If** you know that **ALL** titles are constructed similarily, then this is easily dealt with. Ie. if you are 100% certain, that **all** titles are on the form *Letters followed by .*, then we can easily remove it by `str_remove_all`. This is what is done in `count2`.

**Caveats**

1. This algorithm treats multiple names seperately, such that for Ms. E, her names F and D are treated seperately.
2. It only counts once over a string, so if there are more than one match in the string, it counts as one. This prevents overcounting.
3. It assumes that ALL titles are followed by `.`

**Further Literature**

I highly doubt that this will completely solve your problem, as the data you have provided is an unlucky sample in the sense that there is no matches at all to test against.

Therefore I would suggest you use the following cheat-sheet, to understand further what is going on;

https://evoldyn.gitlab.io/evomics-2018/ref-sheets/R_strings.pdf

Comment: I tried in this way, after a lot of running time the result is the following: N/A for both count1 and 2, with the following  warning : Warning messages:
1: Unknown or uninitialised column: `count1`. 
2: Unknown or uninitialised column: `count2`. .

Comment: and i tried to check this:  tmpName
[1] NA

Comment: Try the following before the `for-loop`; `df$count1 = NA` and  `df$count2 = NA`. This should eliminated the first 2 warnings. But I do not understand why `tmpName = NA`. Did you run the algorithm I provided directly on your own data, or on the data that I provided? Remember that you have to change all relevant variable names in the code that I provided you, in order to apply it to your own data.

Comment: Also - and this is just my opinion - get familiar with the algorithm that I provided on the data that I provided such that you can, eventually, finalize the code to fit your data and solve the problems that your data faces.

Comment: yes i change the algorithm on the basis of my data. Maybe there is too many words in the column Firma togheter with the names. This algorithm captures only the name? or is not able to capture the name if togheter there are words like AK, JG, & Co. ecc..?

Comment: No, that doesn't explain why `tmpName = NA`. The algorithm captures all names that are divided by `,`. So it can't be `NA`, unless some names are seperated differently of course. Ive done this type of work a lot, and there are many pitfalls. So therefore, to help you further you need to 1) Add the modified code to your post by using edit, 2) post the part of the of data where the algorithm gives unexpected results. Otherwise its basically a guessing game.

Comment: but i sow that only in the first column the one of inv_name are divided by , . The one in in the column Firma not, are only posted like I.E. Mark Zhuck. or M. Zhuck. and so on. By the way im now posting my code.

Comment: and i have an idea, maybe is better capture only the first name that appear before the (,). That is the surname. And this might be work. How can I do?